# Handle disabled Button Touch

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I want to handle touches on my disabled button

```
self.closeButton.enabled = NO;
self.closeButtonDisabledRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonDisablePressed)];
[self.closeButton addGestureRecognizer:self.closeButtonDisabledRecognizer];
```

But seems like it doesn't work. Any good solution ?

Comment: Quick thing to check: does disabling also change userInteractionEnabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling is too much like telling the SDK to ignore touches to be what you want.  I suggest instead:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL treatTheCloseButtonAsEnabled;

// replace the synthesized setter
- (void)setTreatTheCloseButtonAsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    self.closeButton.alpha = (enabled)? 1.0 : 0.5;
    // or some other visible indication of the "disabled" state
}

- (IBAction)pressedCloseButton:(id)sender {

    if (self.treatTheCloseButtonAsEnabled) {
        // logic for a regular press
    } else {
        // logic for a disabled press
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, thanks. Thought I can avoid masking button to enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can also use the touch event in the controller.It will be like this(I assume that your close button is added on controller.view):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    touchPoint = [self.view convertPoint:touchPoint toView:_closeButton.superview];

    //to determine wether user touch on you button
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(_closeButton.frame, touchPoint) == NO) {
        return;
    }

    //handle your touch on button here
}
```